# Profiling Laravel Artisan Commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vps

I have a Laravel app running on VPS and I want to do profiling of artisan commands scheduled to run at 5 AM every day but it takes lot of time to complete nearly it completes at 2 PM and I want to make it work more faster.Just to give you the quick overview of the app.Basically the app is connected to Google Adwords API, Bing Ads API and Facebook Ads API.Our Adwords/Bing Account are really really big consider like 200K Keywords under each account.Every day it scans the 200 K Keywords for each account and updates via API, but this automation process takes lot of time and I want to make this work more faster.

Please suggest whats the best way I can speed up the process!

Thanks!

Comment: You could add logs and then check which takes more time

Comment: Or you could split the user population ( 1 segment starts at 5 AM, 1 starts at 6AM etc...)